# dates: Not yet implemented NAbounds=TRUE for this non-numeric and non-character type

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have this dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 
10), dateA = structure(c(14974, 18628, 18628, 18628, 14882, 16800, 
14882, 17835, 17835, 16832, 16556, 16556, 15949, 16801), class = "Date"), 
dateB = structure(c(14610, 15340, 15706, 17501, 14730, NA, 
14700, 16191, 17106, 16801, 15810, 16436, 14655, 15431), class = "Date"), 
dateC = structure(c(18628, 15705, 17500, 18628, 18628, NA, 
18628, 17105, 18628, 18628, 16435, 16556, 15706, 18628), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

    ID      dateA      dateB      dateC
 1:  1 2010-12-31 2010-01-01 2021-01-01
 2:  2 2021-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-12-31
 3:  2 2021-01-01 2013-01-01 2017-11-30
 4:  2 2021-01-01 2017-12-01 2021-01-01
 5:  3 2010-09-30 2010-05-01 2021-01-01
 6:  4 2015-12-31       <NA>       <NA>
 7:  5 2010-09-30 2010-04-01 2021-01-01
 8:  6 2018-10-31 2014-05-01 2016-10-31
 9:  6 2018-10-31 2016-11-01 2021-01-01
10:  7 2016-02-01 2016-01-01 2021-01-01
11:  8 2015-05-01 2013-04-15 2014-12-31
12:  8 2015-05-01 2015-01-01 2015-05-01
13:  9 2013-09-01 2010-02-15 2013-01-01
14: 10 2016-01-01 2012-04-01 2021-01-01
```

I would like to check if dateA is in the interval of dateB and dateC:
My code:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(match= ifelse(between(dateA, dateB, dateC), 1, 0))
```

gives:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `match`.
i `match = ifelse(between(dateA, dateB, dateC), 1, 0)`.
x Not yet implemented NAbounds=TRUE for this non-numeric and non-character type
```

If I remove the row that contains `NA` the code works:

```
df1 %>% 
  slice(-6) %>% 
  mutate(match= ifelse(between(dateA, dateB, dateC), 1, 0))
```

**I want to know, can I leave the row with `NA` and perform my code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a confusion as to which `between` the OP was using because the input object is `data.table` and the code used is `dplyr`.  So, if we assume both packages are loaded, there is a `between` function in each of those packages and depending on which package got loaded last, the `between` from the previous package will get masked.  If use `dplyr::between`, it is not vectorized fully and it is documented in the `?dplyr::between`

> left, right Boundary values (must be scalars).

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(match = +(dplyr::between(dateA, dateB, dateC))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 × 5
      ID dateA      dateB      dateC      match
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <int>
 1     1 2010-12-31 2010-01-01 2021-01-01     1
 2     2 2021-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-12-31     0
 3     2 2021-01-01 2013-01-01 2017-11-30     0
 4     2 2021-01-01 2017-12-01 2021-01-01     1
 5     3 2010-09-30 2010-05-01 2021-01-01     1
 6     4 2015-12-31 NA         NA            NA
 7     5 2010-09-30 2010-04-01 2021-01-01     1
 8     6 2018-10-31 2014-05-01 2016-10-31     0
 9     6 2018-10-31 2016-11-01 2021-01-01     1
10     7 2016-02-01 2016-01-01 2021-01-01     1
11     8 2015-05-01 2013-04-15 2014-12-31     0
12     8 2015-05-01 2015-01-01 2015-05-01     1
13     9 2013-09-01 2010-02-15 2013-01-01     0
14    10 2016-01-01 2012-04-01 2021-01-01     1
```

---

However, it is not the case with `?data.table::between` (based on the error showed in OP's post, it seems that the `between` used was from `data.table`,

> lower - Lower range bound. Either length 1 or same length as x.

> upper - Upper range bound. Either length 1 or same length as x.

but `class` can be an issue though it says otherwise

> x- Any orderable vector, i.e., those with relevant methods for `<=`, such as numeric, character, Date, etc. in case of between and a numeric vector in case of inrange.

Convert to `integer/numeric` from `Date` class and it should work

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(match = +(data.table::between(as.numeric(dateA), 
       as.numeric(dateB), as.numeric(dateC))))
```

-output

```
ID      dateA      dateB      dateC match
 1:  1 2010-12-31 2010-01-01 2021-01-01     1
 2:  2 2021-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-12-31     0
 3:  2 2021-01-01 2013-01-01 2017-11-30     0
 4:  2 2021-01-01 2017-12-01 2021-01-01     1
 5:  3 2010-09-30 2010-05-01 2021-01-01     1
 6:  4 2015-12-31       <NA>       <NA>     1
 7:  5 2010-09-30 2010-04-01 2021-01-01     1
 8:  6 2018-10-31 2014-05-01 2016-10-31     0
 9:  6 2018-10-31 2016-11-01 2021-01-01     1
10:  7 2016-02-01 2016-01-01 2021-01-01     1
11:  8 2015-05-01 2013-04-15 2014-12-31     0
12:  8 2015-05-01 2015-01-01 2015-05-01     1
13:  9 2013-09-01 2010-02-15 2013-01-01     0
14: 10 2016-01-01 2012-04-01 2021-01-01     1
```

By diving deeper, the issue is in the argument `NAbounds` which is `TRUE` by default.  In the OP's data, there is a single `NA` element

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(match = data.table::between(dateA, dateB, dateC))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `match`.
> ℹ `match = data.table::between(dateA, dateB, dateC)`.
> ✖ Not yet implemented NAbounds=TRUE for this non-numeric and non-character type
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

We may need to set this to `FALSE`

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate(match = +(data.table::between(dateA, dateB, dateC, NAbounds = FALSE)))
    ID      dateA      dateB      dateC match
 1:  1 2010-12-31 2010-01-01 2021-01-01     1
 2:  2 2021-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-12-31     0
 3:  2 2021-01-01 2013-01-01 2017-11-30     0
 4:  2 2021-01-01 2017-12-01 2021-01-01     1
 5:  3 2010-09-30 2010-05-01 2021-01-01     1
 6:  4 2015-12-31       <NA>       <NA>    NA
 7:  5 2010-09-30 2010-04-01 2021-01-01     1
 8:  6 2018-10-31 2014-05-01 2016-10-31     0
 9:  6 2018-10-31 2016-11-01 2021-01-01     1
10:  7 2016-02-01 2016-01-01 2021-01-01     1
11:  8 2015-05-01 2013-04-15 2014-12-31     0
12:  8 2015-05-01 2015-01-01 2015-05-01     1
13:  9 2013-09-01 2010-02-15 2013-01-01     0
14: 10 2016-01-01 2012-04-01 2021-01-01     1
```

---

Or may also do a conversion on the `NA` with `as.Date`

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(match = +(data.table::between(dateA, dateB, dateC, 
         NAbounds = as.Date(NA))))
    ID      dateA      dateB      dateC match
 1:  1 2010-12-31 2010-01-01 2021-01-01     1
 2:  2 2021-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-12-31     0
 3:  2 2021-01-01 2013-01-01 2017-11-30     0
 4:  2 2021-01-01 2017-12-01 2021-01-01     1
 5:  3 2010-09-30 2010-05-01 2021-01-01     1
 6:  4 2015-12-31       <NA>       <NA>    NA
 7:  5 2010-09-30 2010-04-01 2021-01-01     1
 8:  6 2018-10-31 2014-05-01 2016-10-31     0
 9:  6 2018-10-31 2016-11-01 2021-01-01     1
10:  7 2016-02-01 2016-01-01 2021-01-01     1
11:  8 2015-05-01 2013-04-15 2014-12-31     0
12:  8 2015-05-01 2015-01-01 2015-05-01     1
13:  9 2013-09-01 2010-02-15 2013-01-01     0
14: 10 2016-01-01 2012-04-01 2021-01-01     1
```

Comment: still gives: `error: Problem with mutate() column match.
i match = +(between(dateA, dateB, dateC)).
x Not yet implemented NAbounds=TRUE for this non-numeric and non-character type
i The error occurred in row 6.`

Comment: thank you for the hint: this works `df1 %>% rowwise %>% mutate(match = +(dplyr::between(dateA, dateB, dateC)))`

Comment: @TarJae it is because there is a conflict in the `between` you are using.  Maybe in your case you are using `data.table::between` instead of `dplyr::between`, but because of the class issue, it gives the error.  Please check my update

Comment: last question. what does `+` there?

Comment: @TarJae You are using `ifelse` on a logical output to convert TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.  Instead directly use `as.integer` or `+` which coerces TRUE/FALSE to its storage values 1/0

Comment: @TarJae I think I understand the issue.  Please check the update

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


df1 %>% 
  mutate(res = +(dateA %within% interval(dateB, dateC)))
#>    ID      dateA      dateB      dateC res
#> 1   1 2010-12-31 2010-01-01 2021-01-01   1
#> 2   2 2021-01-01 2012-01-01 2012-12-31   0
#> 3   2 2021-01-01 2013-01-01 2017-11-30   0
#> 4   2 2021-01-01 2017-12-01 2021-01-01   1
#> 5   3 2010-09-30 2010-05-01 2021-01-01   1
#> 6   4 2015-12-31       <NA>       <NA>  NA
#> 7   5 2010-09-30 2010-04-01 2021-01-01   1
#> 8   6 2018-10-31 2014-05-01 2016-10-31   0
#> 9   6 2018-10-31 2016-11-01 2021-01-01   1
#> 10  7 2016-02-01 2016-01-01 2021-01-01   1
#> 11  8 2015-05-01 2013-04-15 2014-12-31   0
#> 12  8 2015-05-01 2015-01-01 2015-05-01   1
#> 13  9 2013-09-01 2010-02-15 2013-01-01   0
#> 14 10 2016-01-01 2012-04-01 2021-01-01   1
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9,
           10),
    dateA = structure(
      c(
        14974,
        18628,
        18628,
        18628,
        14882,
        16800,
        14882,
        17835,
        17835,
        16832,
        16556,
        16556,
        15949,
        16801
      ),
      class = "Date"
    ),
    dateB = structure(
      c(
        14610,
        15340,
        15706,
        17501,
        14730,
        NA,
        14700,
        16191,
        17106,
        16801,
        15810,
        16436,
        14655,
        15431
      ),
      class = "Date"
    ),
    dateC = structure(
      c(
        18628,
        15705,
        17500,
        18628,
        18628,
        NA,
        18628,
        17105,
        18628,
        18628,
        16435,
        16556,
        15706,
        18628
      ),
      class = "Date"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-14L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)
```